# Add image to Welcome.aml with Sandcastle

Tags: image, sandcastle, xlink

First of, I've searched far and wide about this issue, and it should be working.

I want to add a picture to my Welcome.aml with Sandcastle.
Inside the Welcome.aml:

```
<section>
<title>Short process description</title>
  <content>
    <para>
      A short description
    </para>
    <para>
      <medialinkInLine>
        <image xlink:href="ShortProcess"/>
      </medialinkInLine>
    </para>
  </content>
</section>
```

I've added the image to my media folder and uses the Image ID in xlink:href.
But nothing appears.

Log files mention it here:

Copying images and creating the media map file...
    C:\blaablaaa\blaaaa\Doc\Doc\Media\ShortProcess.jpg -> C:\blaablaaa\blaaaa\Doc\Doc\Help\Working\Media\ShortProcess.jpg 
Generating conceptual topic files

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly medialinkInLine didn't work for me. Even though it worked for a co-worker.

```
<section>
  <title>Short process for BladeSet</title>
  <content>
    <para>
      A rough description of the BladeSet application.
    </para>
    <mediaLink>
        <image xlink:href="Short process for BladeSet"/>
    </mediaLink>
  </content>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5):

I did some documentations for my own projects and tumbled acros a very **important fact**

> [cite]... Also, make sure the **href ID on the image element matches** the
>   **ImageId property** on the image file in the project explorer window.  If
>   you use the Entity References window to list the images in the
>   project, you can drag and drop them from there into the documents and
>   they will be added with the proper element name and ID[/cite]

citation taken from [**Sandcastle discussion forum**](https://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/267501)

*Usage in my latest demo project*
[image: include mediaLink with image - demo]

For further details you may have a look at [**mediaLink description**](http://www.ewoodruff.us/mamlguide/html/34c8823f-8395-4d64-9941-8d156083709c.htm) at sandcastle itself.